# Stack(список), который наследует Vector и стек в котором выполняются методы это одно и тоже?

Tags: java, методы, коллекции, стек

И есть методы у стека?(как у ArrayList например)

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Что такое "Стек который наследует вектор и стек в котором выполняются методы"? Уточните свой вопрос, используйте точные названия классов, приведите примеры кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это одно и то же только с концептуальной точки зрения: работает по принципу "последним пришел, первым ушел" (last in, first out).

Понятно, что при выполнении кода тоже используется какая-то структура/логика для отслеживания методов, но это не стек из стандартной библиотеки классов. Они работают на разных уровнях.